# Why i cannot import org.apache.commons.math3 in Eclipse photon after including jar file and setting build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-photon

I wanted to import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.PoissonDistribution. for this I downloaded "commons-math3-3.6.1.jar " and set the build path. in eclipse .jar files also get included in referenced libraries as shown but still import is not successful.

[image: sample code]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put your code into question not in image with proper code indentation.